# Bootstrap 3 <div> container not aligned

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a little problem with the alignment of my div containers, using Bootstrap 3. There is an overlap of my left sidebar and the top navigation-bar and I don't know why. I deliberately set the z-index to a higher value to show the overlap occurring. Seems like an offset of 11px but I can't explain that. Shouldn't they be aligned edge to edge correctly automatically? The goal is to have a sidebar 220px in width and 100% length.

I wrote some code in HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
include 'core/includes/overall/header.php';
?>
<div class="site-holder">
    <?php include 'core/includes/topNavigation.php' ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <?php include 'core/includes/leftSidebar.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include 'core/includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
</div>
```

This is the site structure of the whole page. After including the top navigation bar I want to use the grid-system to implement a left-sidebar. The code for both is this:

TOP-NAVIGATIONBAR:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MEDIFAKTOR online</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Start</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

LEFT-SIDEBAR:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The style.css used is:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.template-setup {
    padding: 40px 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.site-holder {
    min-height: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.box-holder {
    min-height: 1200px;
}

.content {
}

.left-sidebar {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    color: #80969C;
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because navigation has a class .navbar-fixed-top, bootstrap assigned a `position:fixed` style rule which then removes it from the flow (forgetting the official term right now). Essentially though, other elements don't recognize it as being there. See [this post about css positions](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/). You may have to apply a `margin-top` of the same amount of pixels as the navigation to get it to not overlap. For example, if the navigation bar height was 50px, then you could set the side-bar margin-top to 50px. Hopefully that was the problem. Again, this is assuming that the overflow is happening at the top.